# Whats the schema.org for a social status post?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, microdata, social-networking

I've looked at many schema.org types, but can't find the right one.

I want to mark-up a simple post, which could contain up to 3 OPTIONAL pictures and many comments.

There is DiscussionForumPosting: It expects headline and at least a picture. My posts don't have a headline. It's just the short text. So I guess google would rank you down, if you don't provide one.

SocialMediaPosting: This one is for shared stuff (links, blogs, ...) only?

QAPage: Google allows this one for pages with questions only, no discussions.

What is the right schema for a status-text + (optional) image + comments?

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO" but there is no SEO benefit from finding some random schema to apply to your page.   Google gives rich snippets from some schema, so you should ask the question "what schema gives me this rich snippet" rather than "what schema fits my data".

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I keep seeing people saying that schema is no good for SEO, but Google's web developer's guide does indicate that [structured Schema data is best for SEO](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)

Comment: I'm not here for discussions about SEO. I know rich snippets give you SEO advantages, thats why I added this tag. So if anyone knows best practices to benefit from rich snippets and that fit my needs (without violating googles guidelines), please welcome.